# Problem inheriting BST into black-red tree

Tags: c++

Since black red tree is a binary search tree I have decided to use inheritance for implementation. Here is how in short node inheritance looks in my code:

```
struct BST_node
{
   // public interface here

   int key;
   BST_node* left;
   BST_node* right;
   BST_node* parent;
};

struct BRT_node : BST_node
{
   // public interface here

   NodeColour colour;
};
```

Problem I have encountered with this is pointers in derived class are type of the base class. Therefore I cannot use them in context of derived class without explicit casting. Maybe hiding members and using virtual accesor methods could do the trick, but that would destroy this simple syntax:

node->left = node->parent;

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: There's a reason this is (almost) universally done with templates in C++. At least as it's implemented in C++, inheritance doesn't work very well for this task. Just about the only way to use inheritance for this purpose is to define an abstract interface, with the implementation entirely in the derived class(es).

Comment: You can't insert balance-unaware BST nodes into a red-black tree, but the proposed structure seems to imply that it's allowed. That's where the awkward casting comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with putting all the data members in `BRT_node`?

```
struct BRT_node
{
    int key;
    BRT_node* next;
    BRT_node* prev;
    BRT_node* parent;
    NodeColour colour;
};
```

This way, you get to keep the "nice syntax" of `node->left = node->parent;`.

The problem with using inheritance here is because the red-black tree algorithms require `BRT_node`s, not `BST_node`s. So inheritance in this case isn't appropriate.